# How to set different permission_classes for GET and POST requests using the same URL?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am building endpoints using DRF (Django Rest Framework).

```
django==2.1.5
djangorestframework==3.9.1
django-rest-auth
djangorestframework-jwt
```

I have model "Item" and I want to set different permission_classes for GET and POST requests.

Here is how i do it:

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def item_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        items = Item.objects.all()
        serializer = ItemSerializer(items, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = ItemSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

I want to use one endpoint for all methods, like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/item/', views.item_list),
    path('api/item/<int:pk>/', views.item_details),
]
```

I want to `AllowAny` user for `GET` request method
and check if `isAdminUser` for `POST` request method

Can i do it like in Flask, i.e. one decorator for one method?

Answer (score 9):

Since you are using **Functional Based Views** there is no option to override any methods. What you can do now is, create a new Permission class and include your logic inside it

```
# permissions.py
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser


class MyCustomPermission(IsAdminUser):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return True
        else:
            return super().has_permission(request, view)
```

and use it in your view as,

```
# views.py
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([MyCustomPermission]) # chage is here 
def item_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        items = Item.objects.all()
        serializer = ItemSerializer(items, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = ItemSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

---

---

If your planning to migrate to **Class Based Views**, you could do it by overriding the [**`get_permissions()`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#get_permissionsself) method.
You can find a [simple example here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#introspecting-viewset-actions)

```
def get_permissions(self):
    """
    Instantiates and returns the list of permissions that this view requires.
    """
    if self.request.method == 'GET':
        permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    else:
        permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [class based](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/) views, define and use [custom permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider defining two separate functions with different permission classes for "get" and "post".

```
@api_view(['GET')
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def item_list_get(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        items = Item.objects.all()
        serializer = ItemSerializer(items, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([isAdminUser])
def item_list_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = ItemSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```